# How to start a process detached from PowerShell such that terminal session is not started?

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to start an application's executable from `powershell` using `Start-Process`. I have tried this process with some applications and it worked just fine. That is, after launching:

- Program launches
- Powershell is ready to receive the next command.
- Terminal session/console output from the program does **not** 'attach' to `powershell`

However, there is one application, which after launching with `Start-Process`, I cannot enter subsequent commands until I do `Ctrl-C` to close the terminal, where the output of the application is being displayed.

This script is not supposed to be interactive in any way. It is intended to run remotely and should not launch an interactive session so that my `powershell` script can carry on with subsequent commands.

Here is the function. The function is identical to the functions used with those other programs that launch just fine without a terminal session.

```
function Start-MyExample {
    Start-Process -FilePath "MyExample.exe" -WorkingDirectory "C:\Users\MyExample\Documents\ExampleSubDir\MyExample" 
    }
```

I then call it with:

```
> Start-MyExample
```

I've also tried adding the `-PassThru` option but that didn't fix it.

How can I prevent the terminal session from being created?

**Edit**

It actually looks like I can enter a command after I run `Start-MyEexample` and output starts becoming visible. It becomes jumbled with the program output. But after I press enter, the command runs fine. After the subsequent command runs and displays, the program doesn't display anymore. Strange.

Spoke too soon. It seems like another program with a console session clears the entire `powershell` screen and it starts its own console session with no opportunity to interact with `powershell`.

Comment: In case you're running on a Unix-like platform: `-NoNewWindow` is invariably implied there, so the new process is connected to the caller's terminal, and, without `-Wait`, any output from the process will arrive asynchronously, potentially interfering with the PowerShell session.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thanks for the explanation. I'm running on Windows. Is there a way for me to just launch and 'detach', such that the program just runs and I can continue to use powershell without any involvement from the launched program?

Comment: On Windows, if you use neither `-NoNewWindow` nor `-Wait`, the new process should always launch asynchronously, detached from the caller's console.

Comment: To put it differently: the symptom you describe would imply a bug in `Start-Process`. On an incidental note: in local invocations, `Start-Process`-launched processes live on independently of the caller's session, whereas in remote invocations they are terminated when the calling session ends (if still alive).

Comment: I see. Yes, I am not using `-NoNewWindow` nor `-Wait`. So if it is a bug then what can I do?

Comment: If you're using Windows PowerShell: you're likely out of luck, because only high-impact bugs have a chance of getting fixed. If you're using PowerShell (Core) 7+ and you have a reproducible case, you can open an issue at  https://aka.ms/psfeedback